# iOS: UIDatePicker returning date in Arabic

Tags: ios, objective-c, datepicker, localization, arabic

My phone's language is Arabic but I want to choose date in english only. I have used calendar as well as locale property of date picker but none is working. I want to get date in English only. My code is as follows:

```
 UIDatePicker *datePicker  = [[UIDatePicker alloc]init];
[datePicker setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 100, self.view.frame.size.width, 216.0)];
datePicker.datePickerMode = UIDatePickerModeDate;
[datePicker setLocale: [NSLocale localeWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"]];
[datePicker addTarget:self action:@selector(updateDateField:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
 NSCalendar *gregorianCalendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];
[datePicker setCalendar:gregorianCalendar];
[self.view addSubview:datePicker];


-(void)updateDateField : (UIDatePicker*)datePicker{
NSLog(@"____ %@",datePicker.date);}
```

The output is: ٢٠١٤-٠٣-٠٩ ١٠:٣٦:٤١ +0000 but I want the output in english only so that I can store the selected date on the server

Comment: No need to set local and calendar of datePicker for that. Comment that two line and check once.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use **DateFormatter** for this. I don't now what format your need send to server. So this is shot example from apple:

```
let RFC3339DateFormatter = DateFormatter()
RFC3339DateFormatter.locale = Locale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
RFC3339DateFormatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZZZZZ"
RFC3339DateFormatter.timeZone = TimeZone(forSecondsFromGMT: 0)

let date = Date()
let string = RFC3339DateFormatter.stringFromDate(date)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using a NSDateFormatter and set the locale to it, then get stringFromDate from the dateController and the date you already have.

Answer (score 0):

`NSLog(@"____ %@",datePicker.date)` will call the `datePicker.date.description` by default to format the output string. and the default `NSDate` description will use the system default locale that is why you got Arabic output.

`-(NSString *)description` is `NSObject`'s method which is called when a subclass of `NSObject` is ‘converted to a string’. `NSDate` itself doesn't include any locale information. But `NSDate`'s description method will create a formatter and use the system's locale.

If you want it to be somewhere in your UI, you should not use default description method, you have to create your own `DateFormatter` to format the output with correct locale and format you want.

Alternatively you can make an extension to `NSDate` and overwrite description function with your customised `DateFormatter`.